# Will anything that's written in c/c++ be rerwritten in rust?

Tags: c++, c, rust

Will anything that's written in c/c++ be rerwritten in rust?

for maintainance, even for performance?

Comment: I have a C program running on a vending machine that has been unchanged for 30 years and is running without issue, and the chip will continue to be available for decades more. What benefits would rewriting it give me?

Comment: An old but still-relevant blog on rewriting code: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/04/06/things-you-should-never-do-part-i/

Answer (score 3):

*Anything*? Sure. I mean, there's literally 50 years of legacy code out there, *something* will almost certainly be ported.

*Everything*? No way in hell. I mean, there's literally 50 years of legacy code out there - it *can't* be.

Comment: There's fortran code still in the common math libraries that C uses.  Will that ever be rewritten?  Only if someone thinks they can optimize it better... otherwise, we'll still have fortran and c and everything else when rust is the primary language.